# How can i link the mounted folder to Laravel project?

Tags: linux, laravel, ubuntu, ubuntu-20.04

I have a Laravel project, which placed here:

```
/home/user/www/example.com
```

We attached a new storage to vds and mounted it for

```
/home/user/www/storage
```

folder.

After that we need add symbolic link from
/home/user/www/storage to /home/user/www/example.com/storage
, but we can not do it, because the last one is already exists and contains needed files.

How can we link it for more space to storage folder in the project?

terminal output:

```
ln -s /home/user/www/storage /home/user/www/example.com/
ln: failed to create symbolic link '/home/user/www/example.com/storage': File exists
```

Comment: note that on Unix/BSD, and Linux, too, they are "directories" and not the Windows concept of "folders" which is not the same thing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Option 1**

You can link it to another place *inside* the `storage` folder and create a separate disk

```sh
$ ln -s /home/user/www/storage/more-space /home/user/www/example.com/
```

Inside your `config/filesystem.php` you can add an additional disk

```
// config/filesystem.php
'disks' => [
  'more-space' => [
    'local' => [
        'driver' => 'local',
        'root' => storage_path('more-space'),
    ],
  ]
]
```

and work with it `Storage::disk('more-space')`.

**Option 2**

1. You move everything that is inside your current `storage` folder into your new folder `/home/user/www/example.com/`
2. Remove your `storage` folder with `rm -rf /home/user/www/storage`
3. Symlink the new folder `ln -s /home/user/www/storage /home/user/www/example.com/`

Comment: Thank you!
I'll prefer the first one. But for better understanding, is it possible to set the /home/user/www/example.com/storage folder for old content and for more-space content both?

Comment: Yes, of course. Just save new content to `storage/more-content` and leave the old data where it currently is. If you mix then you just need to find a way inside Laravel to check both folder, `storage/fileX` or `storage/more-content/fileX`.